# Enable/Disable killing a running listener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm working with an application using spring framework and rabbitMQ which act as a listener on listening and dequeue data whenever data exist in the queue. What I want is the listener cannot be killed when it's processing, it just can only be killed while it is listening and there isn't data exist in the queue. So does anybody have any ideas about it? Is it possible? And if it is, what should I do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but any in-process messages will be requeued and redelivered (by default).